# Can I export full database and import it in a fresh newer CiviCRM version?

Tags: import, database, export, upgrade

I am experiencing difficulties during CiviCRM upgrade from 4.7.14 to 4.7.31 or 5.1, namely, fields like **contact.birth_date** get broken. (More: [DB Error after upgrading 4.7.x to 5.1 (Drupal)](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25098/db-error-after-upgrading-4-7-x-to-5-1-drupal))

I have noticed that during CiviCRM version update, there is a process of sequential updates that seem to also include database updates.

I wonder, if it is possible to export full database and re-import it in a newer version fresh CiviCRM installation?

Answer (score 4):

Aivars, If the problem you facing is something related to report then i would suggest to fix the report rather wasting time exporting-importing data/structure from 2 different instances. The problem you facing has nothing to do with db structure. The error in report might be

1. Any installed extension might be conflicting with report code, so you can probably try after disabling/Uninstalling each extension.
2. Try creating new report from template, sometimes the form values stored in db for saved reports might have values that are missing/renamed in newwer version.

If you still willing to give a try for exporting-importing data/structure then [here](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC21/Ensuring+Schema+Integrity+on+Upgrades) is a way how you can do it. The doc is pretty old so you will to need to manipulate with the version you trying.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Pradeep, would it be enough to disable the extensions to test or should I uninstall them as well?

Comment: disable would be fine. Uninstall might result in loss of any setting or data. Important note : Take backup before playing around with enable/disable

Comment: thank you for advice. (**1**) Disabling all extensions did not help. (**2**) Creating new report from template did not help either. The upgrade to v4.7.30. (or newer) just break things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can export database and after importing in the new installation, just run civicrm upgrade script: `BASE_URL/civicrm/upgrade?reset=1` that will update your database.

Comment: This is only correct if it's the same version.