# Update Indices fails on 4.7.29

Tags: issues, upgrade, indices

With successful update from 4.7.25 to 4.7.29 there is a **Performance warning: Missing Indices** in CiviCRM System Status. When I click the *Update Indices* button, the error appears

`Operation failed: Update Indices
DB Error: unknown error`

Enabling debug mode does not provide any additional info.

[image: Operation failed: Update Indices]

Comment: Just wondering why you are only upgrading to 4.7.29 ?  There are lots of fixes since then in later versions.

Comment: @Aidan, I was trying to do step by step upgrade, because upgrading to 4.7.30 (or later) got me into these problems: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25098/db-error-after-upgrading-4-7-x-to-5-1-drupal

Comment: Ok, that makes sense if 4.7.29 is an intermediate step.  However, you can leave the Update Indices thing - that changed several times in releases around that time.  It was a warning that indices were less than optimal but is not an error.  When you eventually get to current versions you can fix it then if the warning still shows.

Answer (score 2):

We had similar problem this before and had to manually run mysql commands to fix the indices. This [link](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18739/problem-fixing-missing-indexes-after-upgrade-to-4-7) might be useful to solve the problem.

HTH

Pradeep